# Does sensor type affect image quality?

Tags: sensor, image-quality, camera-design

I've recently discovered snapsort.com and use it to compare other cameras with the one I own. When comparing Pentax k10D with the K-x model I learned that the K-x has a CMOS sensor and that

> CMOS-family sensors often produce better quality images

The [explanation](http://snapsort.com/learn/sensor/type) for that is

> [CMOS sensors] also permit more integrated designs which can cut down on noise gain and provide the opportunity for a cleaner image.

which I take to mean that lower noise is due to better IC designs made possible with CMOS, not the sensor type itself.

- Is this a meaningful  distinction?
- All things being equal, do CMOS sensor produce better quality images that CCD?

Comment: 1. snapsort.com just compare specs and do not provide any analysis. 2. Think about the reason most of medium format backs are CCD

Comment: @RomeoNinov I don't know what medium format is (I'm new to the world of photography) so you've given me something to read on. My intuition says that CCD takes in the _entire_ image at once, contrary to CMOS, which reads it _row by row_ (or at least not all at once), and is therefore superior to it. Yet CMOS is cheaper to work with, which can enable the manufacturer to pack extra features for the same cost.

Comment: rath, do some search for medium format digital camera and you will see interesting articles. And yes, CMOS is cheaper because this technology is developed not only for optical sensors, but for different integrated circuits also. CCD is used mostly for optical sensors so do not become so deep developed. And yes, you can get from CCD entire image at once, if I am not wrong this is named electronic shutter. But this is only one point.

Comment: **EVERY** variation of sensor design affects image quality to one degree or another.

Answer (score -1):

Yess Sensor type affects image quality

actually
CCD sensors are expensive. it's more sensitive to light and delivers better ISO performance.

where CMOS production process is more automated and its relatively cheaper so its used in more quantity.

google the CMOS\CCD Image sensor layout